# Couchbase CRUD operations with query language

Tags: spring, crud, couchbase

Im using couchbase 4.0 beta version. And Im successfully able to save the objects into the bucket using rest service. Now I need to access the bucket and do GET, UPDATE and DELETE operations using queries.

This is the my sample object in bucket.

```
{
       "id": "friend$43403778",
       "domain": "FRIEND",
       "profileId": 43403778,
       "screenName": "49ers",
       "name": "San Francisco 49ers",
       "profileUrl": "http://twitter.com/49ers",
       "description": "Official Twitter account of the five-time Super Bowl Champion San Francisco #49ers.",
       "friendsCount": 121,
       "followersCount": 964650,
       "timeZone": "Pacific Time (US & Canada)",
       "utcOffset": -25200,
       "location": "Santa Clara, CA",
       "profileCreated": 1243629277000
   }
```

Now I want to get this object using **id**. But **id value contains special character** so my query doesn't works for it. How can I access it???

This is my code snippet which I tried to get this.It doesn't gives me the 300 error code syntax error.

```
        String strQuery = "SELECT * FROM twitter WHERE id=" + id;
        Bucket bucket = singletonBucket.getBucket();
        QueryResult queryResult = bucket.query(Query.simple(strQuery));
        List<QueryRow> result = Collections.emptyList();

        if (!queryResult.finalSuccess()) {
            log.error("Error occur while retrieving TwitterProfile document for id: {}",id);
            String errorStr = "";
            for (JsonObject error : queryResult.errors()) {
                errorStr = error.toString() + ". ";
                log.error("{}", error);
            }
            throw new DataAccessException(errorStr);
        } else {
            result = queryResult.allRows();
            for(QueryRow row: result){
                Object doc = row.value().get(AppConstants.BUCKET_NAME);
                TwitterProfile twitterProfile = objectMapper.readValue(doc.toString(), TwitterProfile.class);
                twitterProfileList.add(twitterProfile);
            }
            log.info("Successfully found {} TwitterProfile record for id {}",twitterProfileList.size(), id);
            return twitterProfileList.size()>0 ?twitterProfileList.get(0):"";
        }
```

If I tried to get the record using **profileId** It also doesnt work.
How can I write the simple queries for this bucket.
These are the queries which I tried. Also my bucket name is **twitter**

```
String strQuery = "SELECT * FROM twitter WHERE domain=" + AppConstants.DOMAIN_FRIEND;
String strQuery = "DELETE FROM twitter WHERE domain=" + AppConstants.DOMAIN_FRIEND;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When building your query you have to use quotes to indicate your id is a string. Try adding quotes around your id when building your query:

```
String strQuery = "SELECT * FROM twitter WHERE id='" + id + "'";
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I already tried it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Can you post your actual error message? When using your snippet, twitter stuff removed and my own bucket name inserted, I get an error message that looks like this: `{"msg":"syntax error - at $43403778","code":3000}`. Did you mean error code 3000? When adding the single quotes around `id` like in my example, the query succeeds.

Comment: If I pass it without quotes it gives the error which you mentioned. But if i add quotes there is no errors but it return nothing. That mean there is no output for the query.  This is my query which I tried. `String strQuery = "SELECT * FROM twitter WHERE id='" + id + "'";`

Comment: OK, your code snippet does not show where the variable `id` comes from. Can you do a simple test, make sure the example document you posted is in your bucket, then hardcode `id` like so: `String id = "friend$43403778"`. Without seeing the rest of your code we can't tell if there is any additional preprocessing of `id` ex. encoding of that character.

Comment: There is no output for the query if I hardcode the value. My new query is `String strQuery = "SELECT * FROM twitter WHERE id='friend$16332223'";`

Comment: Did you got any output.  Can you try it on the couchbase shell Go to bin folder first  `cd /opt/couchbase/bin` then type and enter `./cbq -engine=http://localhost:8093` and try to run your query if it works let me know.

Comment: Yes, this query works in cbq: `SELECT * FROM retail WHERE id='friend$43403778';` (my bucket is named retail). Again, please make sure you have the document that you posted above in your bucket, and use the `id` from that document, your comment has a different `id`.

The query running successfully should solve the problem stated, the special character is not actually in issue, you just need to place the id value in quotes in your query. The query itself returning no results is a separate issue.

Comment: I tried another record and its not return in shell. Im using couchbase 4.0 beta in cent os 6. output in cbq: `[509661@els-d60685 bin]$ cd /opt/couchbase/bin
[509661@els-d60685 bin]$ ./cbq -engine=http://localhost:8093
cbq> 
cbq> select * from twitter where id='friend$24109979';
{
    "requestID": "cf62d159-5047-44e2-aea0-ffab5e8a430d",
    "signature": {
        "*": "*"
    },
    "results": [
    ],
    "status": "success",
    "metrics": {
        "elapsedTime": "486.168502ms",
        "executionTime": "471.54924ms",
        "resultCount": 0,
        "resultSize": 0
    }
}
`

Comment: I found the issue. query suppose to be String strQuery = "SELECT * FROM `twitter` WHERE id='"+id+"'"; Now Its working fine. :) In here bucket name has to be within ` these two symbols.

Comment: Yes, that response means that the query was successful, no errors at all. There were no results, which means your query just doesn't return any results. Please double check that the `id` you are searching for is actually in your data set, you used another `id` value which is not from the example document you posted in your original post, so I cannot be sure if the query actually SHOULD return results or not.

Comment: Hi Neero - the backticks around the table name are necessary if you have something like a - in the table name. if you have a single word with no special characters then they are not strictly necessary. Can you run the exact query with the hardcoded `id` that was successful for you without the backticks to ensure that is actually the issue? As you can see I did not need backticks, I'm also using Couchbase 4.0 Beta.

Comment: Sometimes its not working again with backticks. Also the without backticks Its working but sometimes. I was create the primary index using this query last time. `CREATE PRIMARY INDEX ON twitter` Now I changed it to `CREATE PRIMARY INDEX ON twitter USING GSI` Thats how it works last time. But its not consistent yet. Sometimes Im getting nothing for the same query.

Comment: Thanks for your help bro. This is confusing.

Comment: Sure thing, just really want to find the root of your problem. Are you using the same `id` in your query every time you run it?

Comment: Yep also I double checked the bucket is that in bucket or not.